# Webview not clearing previous page Android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a webView which changes its load url on a button click.
Everything is working fine except the loaded url seems to be not cleared properly.

The previous url is loaded in webview and is displayed just before the new url appears. I tried using

**webView.clearView()**,

**webView.clearHistory()**,

**webView.loadUrl("about:blank")**,

**webView.clearCache(true)**

and also tried clearing the cookies. But nothing helps clearing the webview properly.

I also tried webView.destroy(); but the webView is destroyed fully as I am nt able to load the next url.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This order worked for me

```
        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.clearHistory();
        clearCookies(this); // Activity context


 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void clearCookies(Context context)
    {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
            CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
        } else
        {
            CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr=CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
            cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
            CookieManager cookieManager=CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
            cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
            cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
            cookieSyncMngr.sync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: still the problem persists. Im trying to load a url that is manually typed into a Edit text. The url loads when i press a button. But the first webview stays in the View for some time before the next url is loaded. Even after applying your technique, the problem is unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this function in your MainActivity.java ?

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:") || url.startsWith("market:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No..I am using a fragment